# Javascript disabling input fields 

Tags: javascript, forms

I am looking for a javascript function. which will disable the entered (filled) text field on submit. So when the user logs in back the filled text box has to remain disabled. I have tried a code, but here what happens is on clicking the sumbit the contents in the text field gets deleted.

```
    <html> 
    <head> 
    <script> 
    function enableDisable(){ 
    var disable = true; 
    var arglen = arguments.length; 
    var startIndex = 0; 
    var frm = document.example1;//change appropriate form name 
    if (arglen>0){ 
    if (typeof arguments[0]=="boolean") { 
    disable=arguments[0]; 
    if (arglen>1) startIndex=1; 
    } 
    for (var i=startIndex;i<arglen;i++){ 
    obj = eval("frm."+arguments[i]); 
    if (typeof obj=="object"){ 
     if (document.layers) { 
    if (disable){ 
    obj.onfocus=new Function("this.blur()"); 
    if (obj.type=="text") obj.onchange=new Function("this.value=this.defaultValue"); 
    } 
     else { 
     obj.onfocus=new Function("return"); 
    if (obj.type=="text") obj.onchange=new Function("return"); 
     } 
    } 
    else obj.disabled=disable; 
     } 
     } 
    } 
     } 
     </script> 
     </head> 
      <body> 
       <form name="example1"> 


      Text Field: <input type="text" name="text1"> 
      <br> 
      <input type="submit" name="control1" onclick="enableDisable(this.submit,'text1','submit','select1')"> 

      </form> 
      </body> 
      </html>
```

please do guide.

Comment: In the future, try to include your code along with your question.  Also, this is pretty simple, and you could have Googled it.  These two reasons are probably why you're getting downvoted.

Comment: It's very hard to tell from your question what you actually want to do. Also, when you write something like "I have tried a code" in a technical question, you should see a big flashing sign in your mind saying "quote the code you tried" (just like "I get an error" should trigger a big flashing sign saying "quote the error verbatim").

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `submit` function returns false if you don't want the page to refresh.  The code you're looking for is `document.getElementById('insertIdOfTextFieldHere').style.readonly = "readonly";`

Comment: The question is vague as all get out, but "when the user logs in back" sounds like they want the field disabled when the user has been away and comes back.

Comment: Yeah.  I was basing my answer on the first two sentences.  I'd need to know more to answer the middle bit about logins.

Comment: i am designing a form.which has a login.just like any other form which requires the user to login and enter the details in the form.The user can logout even without entering all the details.I want to give the user such provision that when he logs in the details which are not entered can be entered.

Comment: and what is your problem with this answer?